# Dropping filtered rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter phone numbers and drop filtered phone numbers. I couldn't combine these conditions into 1 filter, so I made two filters. When I drop by 1 filter everything works fine. But when I drop by second filter I get an error. But anyway I get a properly filtered data frame.

What I need to change, to go without any error?

```py
import pandas as pd
            
df = pd.DataFrame({"Phone" :['+77013655566','87014324366','7014324366','11111','999999','43434343','+77015452313','7012334212','87010956612', '7777777', '8888888']})

print(df)
           Phone
0   +77013655566
1    87014324366
2     7014324366
3          11111
4         999999
5       43434343
6   +77015452313
7     7012334212
8    87010956612
9        7777777
10       8888888

phone_filter = ((df['Phone'].map(str) == '8888888') |   
                (df['Phone'].map(str) ==  '7777777')) 
        
phone_filter2 = ((df['Phone'].map(str).str[0] != '8') &   
                (df['Phone'].map(str).str[0] !=  '7') &   
                (df['Phone'].map(str).str[0] !=  '+'))   
        
df.drop(df[phone_filter].index, inplace = True)
df.drop(df[phone_filter2].index, inplace = True)

<ipython-input-83-80183cb110d3>:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Expected output:

```py
print(df)
          Phone
0  +77013655566
1   87014324366
2    7014324366
6  +77015452313
7    7012334212
8   87010956612
```

Comment: What is the expected output? note that the first filter is no effective since it compares a char to a string longer than one char

Comment: Updated my question with the expected output. Actually, I get an expected output with this code. The problem is, that I get an error.

Comment: Can u read question one more time, please. I had a mistake in my question.

Comment: You want to drop every number that starts with '8', '7' or '+'?

Comment: I want to drop every number that doesn't start with '8', '7' or '+', also want to drop specific numbers like: '8888888', '7777777'.

Comment: When you first drop the index acquired by `phone_filter`, you change the shape of the dataframe (by removing some rows). But the shape of your second filter `phone_filter2` remains the same. That's why pandas throw up a warning when you call `df[phone_filter2]`. It just wants you to know it'll _reindex_ to match the index/shape.

Comment: Other than that, you code works just fine. It's quite redundant, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
invalid_numbers = ['8888888', '7777777']
df[(~df.Phone.isin(invalid_numbers)) & (df.Phone.str[0].isin(['8','7','+']))]
```

Output:

```
          Phone
0  +77013655566
1   87014324366
2    7014324366
6  +77015452313
7    7012334212
8   87010956612
```